# Not allowed to use reflection in asp.net mvc2 running on a secure server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, https

I'm trying to deploy a web site on a secure server, but I'm having problems with reflection.
I guess this have something to do with security, but I'm not quite sure.

The error occurs when doing Assembly.GetTypes()

```
ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +105
```

If I just ignore these exceptions and continue to load from assemblies, nothing is loaded. Seems like I'm not allowed to do this for any assemblies at all. When I run in a non secure webserver, everything works ok. I don't know much about IIS, mvc or .net security policies, so any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Heres the code causing the exception:

```
private static IEnumerable<IModule> GetModules()
{
    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()) // <--- This one throws
        {
            var moduleType = type.GetInterface(typeof(IModule).Name);
            if (moduleType != null)
            {
                IModule module = null;
                try
                {
                    module = (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
                }
                catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
                {
                    // GetInterface() get's all interfaces with the same
                    // name, so we'll just skip those who isn't ours
                    logger.Warn("Could not load module", ex);
                }

                if( module != null)
                    yield return module;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure you're not loading any dynamic assemblies. I had a similar problem with MVC and dynamic assemblies but I'm not sure if it's the same.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "secure server" and "non secure server"?  Do you mean trust levels, HTTP / HTTPS, or something else?  (I assume you're talking about trust levels based on your error, but just wanted to confirm.)  Also, the exception message is telling you to look at the LoaderExceptions property of the exception object.  Please post that.  You can also look at the Types that were successfully loaded via the exception object's Types property.

Comment: @Levi: It's HTTP/HTTPS I'm thinking of. I'm not sure how I can look at the LoaderException as I don't have VS installed on that computer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. It's not related to HTTP/HTTPS at all.

This post helped me on track http://forums.asp.net/t/1196710.aspx

Some assemblies in a dependant module didn't get copied to the output folder. My development machine and the test server has these in GAC, so everything works there.

I added these components explicitly, and now everything works.

Thanks for your time